# How to create an alias for phpmyadmin in apache?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

Using Ubuntu 16.04, apache2.

I have the following virtual host in apache, but my URL `http://example.com/phpmyadmin` gives a 404 error. Any ideas?

From looking at other stackoverflow posts, this *should* work, but it isn't working. I'm fairly new to the Linux/Apache world (if this was on IIS I'd be fine!) so if you can give any pointers that'd also be appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.org

Alias /phpmyadmin/ /user/share/phpmyadmin/

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
    php_value include_path .
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
</IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your error logs say? Try removing the trialing / from the Alias /phpmyadmin

Comment: Tried it with and without /, no difference. Anything specific I'm looking for in the logs?

Comment: Should show something in the error logs about attempting to load this phpmyadmin page or that it "can't be found"

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing in the error log even mentioning phpmyadmin.

Comment: Did you install phpMyAdmin using the package manager or download it yourself from phpmyadmin.net?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/387074